# How can I transform an SVG path without transforming applied gradient/filter?

Tags: svg, svg-filters, svg-transforms

Given some simple SVG like:

```xml
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0); stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50"
    fill="url(#gradient1)"
  />
</svg>
```

which renders a square with a vertical, two-color gradient like so:

[image: square with vertical, two-color gradient]

I would like to be able to rotate the square *without* rotating the gradient. In other words, I’d like the gradient to use global (user space) coordinates independent of the path coordinates so that the render looks like so:

[image: diamond with vertical, two-color gradient]

But applying a transform to the path doesn’t work this way. When I give the path a transform like so:

```xml
  <rect x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50"
    fill="url(#gradient1)"
    transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)"
  />
```

It seems like it first renders the shape with its gradient, and *then* applies the transform such that the gradient is transformed with the path:

[image]

Is there any way to apply the gradient to the path *after* any transformations?

Comment: You could wrap the `<rect>` in a `<g>` and apply the filter to the `<g>` instead

Comment: @Sean That doesn’t seem to change anything in the rendered output. The gradient is still rotated. Did you try it? If so, maybe post the code as an answer in case I'm misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread and thought that was a filter instead of a fill.

Comment: @Sean Same happens to me when applying a `filter="..."`. It seems to render the filter, _then_ rotates everything rather than applying the filter to the rotated path. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use a mask (or clip path) to mask off the rotated rectangle. Let's say that you would like to animate the rotation, then this solution would be easier to handle.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0); stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50" fill="white" transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient1)" mask="url(#m1)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a gradientTransform to your gradient definition (and drop the userSpaceUnits) aka:

```html
   <svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
<linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100%"  gradientTransform ="rotate(-45) translate(0 0.2)">
  <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
  <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
  <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,255,0); stop-opacity:1" />
</linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50"
fill="url(#gradient1)" transform="rotate(45, 50, 50)"
  />
</svg>
```